# Iterators Java methods

Tags: java, inheritance, iterator

I have two questions:

1. I want to do a method that use as iterator. I have array of arrays and I want that I can go with for loop on this iterator and receive every time the next item.
2. I have an arrayList in abstract class that in inheritance classes I initialize this ArrayList with Strings and in the sec time I intialize this with linkedList.

So If I have to declare the type of this ArrayList what I have to write? I tried ArrayList(Object) but I want to know if there is better way to do this.

I tried

```
ArrayList<Object>
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Could you show us some of your code to help illustrate the problem?

Comment: "*So If I have to declear the type of this ArrayList what I have to write? I tried `ArrayList(Objact)`*" you should take a look at [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html).

Comment: You should implement Iterable interface. Examples for this implementation will be a good start.

Comment: I explain somthing. 
in the abstract class I create protected ArrayList(Object) listA;
In the inheritenc class I use listA=new ArrayList<String>(20);
So this is a problem or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a type to be able to be both an `ArrayList` and a `LinkedList` then use a `List` since it is the parent interface to both of those.